# Rspec passes on individual spec files but fails on whole directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a model section that belongs to course, teacher, and semester.

I have a Factory Girl definition that looks like this:

```
factory :section do
  course
  teacher
  semester
  sequence(:section_number) {|n| "n"}
  days_of_week ["M", "W", "F", ""]
  time_block "7:45-9:15"
end
```

I have no uniqueness validations on any of the associated models or on section.

I have 2 rspec files where I need to create a section. If I run rspec on each file individually, they both pass, but if I run rspec on the whole directory, one fails every time because section is nil. Also it's not the same file that fails each time...

```
     Failure/Error: section = FactoryGirl.create(:section)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

Even if I call Factory Girl in the rails console, it will create the first section correctly and any subsequent calls results in a nil section.

I'm out of ideas on why this would be happening... I have plenty of other factories that work properly.

Comment: Would you add your models/section.rb code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with my Factory as I had originally suspected.

I had an before_create method on section.rb that was converting an array to a string. I changed the way that was working and that fixed the issue.

before:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :days_of_week

 before_create :array_to_s


 belongs_to :course
 belongs_to :teacher
 belongs_to :semester
 has_many :student_section_enrollments
 has_many :students, :through => :student_section_enrollments


 WEEKDAYS = ["M", "TU", "W", "TH", "F"]

 TIME_BLOCKS = ["7:45-9:15", "9:30-11:00"]

 def set_next_section_number(semester)
   self.section_number = semester.sections.count + 1
 end

 def current_semester_sections
    @current_sections = Section.where("description LIKE ?", current_semester)
 end

 private

 def array_to_s
   self.days_of_week = self.days_of_week.reject!(&:empty?)
   self.days_of_week = self.days_of_week.join(', ')
 end
```

end

After:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :days_of_week, Array
 before_save :remove_empty_days_of_week


 belongs_to :course
 belongs_to :teacher
 belongs_to :semester
 has_many :student_section_enrollments
 has_many :students, :through => :student_section_enrollments


 WEEKDAYS = ["M", "TU", "W", "TH", "F"]

 TIME_BLOCKS = ["7:45-9:15", "9:30-11:00"]

 def set_next_section_number(semester)
   self.section_number = semester.sections.count + 1
 end

 def current_semester_sections
    @current_sections = Section.where("description LIKE ?", current_semester)
 end

 def days_of_week_string
   days_of_week.join(', ')
 end

 private

 def remove_empty_days_of_week
   if self.days_of_week.present?
     self.days_of_week.reject!(&:empty?)
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your consequent `selection` factory is never unique. You are using `sequence` for `section_number`, but eventually using `String` "n".

Try replacing
`sequence(:section_number) {|n| "n"}` with
`sequence(:section_number) {|n| n}` instead and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't even need a sequence there, as there is no uniqueness validation on there, but thank you for pointing out the error with the quotes.

Comment: Oh. To be honest, I have had difficulties with FactoryGirl too, whenever the specs amount went in hundreds. Try to use `DatabaseCleaner` with truncation strategy. It has worked for me in several occasions.